# how to override list.phtml for custom theme in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I have been trying to override

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

in my custom theme but with no success.

**What I've tried:** copied list from above and paste/modified in

> app/design/frontend/myvendorfolder/mythemefolder/Magento_Catalog/templates/list.phtml

After that i run `php bin/magento cache:clean` and

> rm -r pub/static/frontend/
>
> var/view_preprocessed/
>
> var/cache/
>
> var/page_cache/

clear my browser cache but it didn't work.

Is this the right way to do it? I have successfully modified `Magento_Contact` form exactly the same way.

can anyone help please?

thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the template override correctly, you missed to have one more folder called "product"

`app/design/frontend/myvendorfolder/mythemefolder/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Comment: Thank's yappan I was answering my own question as i investigated further you reply. I really appreciate for clarifying. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you paste the `.phtml` file under `app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Also copy the layout files which you need `app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout/layoutfile`

Then Run `php` `bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 0):

Oops I am going to answer my own question as I incorrectly place inside templates but in fact there needs to have another folder called  **product** the key folder missing.

So the final path works for me is:
**app/design/frontend/myvendorfolder/mythemefolder/Magento_Catalog/templates/*product*/list.phtml**

thank you.